# Something wrong with Android SDK source code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

[image]

[image]

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bigbaozi.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }



}
```

I have download all version of API(Documentation for Android SDK,SDK platform,Google APIs,Sources for Android SDK).RelativeLayout can not recognize that isLayoutRtl() is belong to it's superclass View.It seems that RelativeLayout.java does't link to View.java.Same thing happened in other Class file.Is there something wrong with my AS(2.1.2)?

Edit:
Rebuild project:

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :library:generateDebugSources, :library:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :library:compileDebugSources, :library:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:clean
:library:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileLint
:library:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:library:checkReleaseManifest
:library:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42211Library
:library:prepareReleaseDependencies
:library:compileReleaseAidl
:library:compileReleaseRenderscript
:library:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:library:mergeReleaseShaders
:library:compileReleaseShaders
:library:generateReleaseAssets
:library:mergeReleaseAssets
:library:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseResources
:library:mergeReleaseResources
:library:processReleaseManifest
:library:processReleaseResources
:library:generateReleaseSources
:library:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:library:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:library:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:library:extractReleaseAnnotations
:library:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseResources
:library:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:library:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:library:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:library:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:library:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:library:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:library:bundleRelease
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2320Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72330Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareMeEverythingOverscrollDecorAndroid103Library
:app:prepareMyApplicationLibraryUnspecifiedLibrary
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:incrementalDebugAndroidTestJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources
:library:checkDebugManifest
:library:prepareDebugDependencies
:library:compileDebugAidl
:library:compileDebugRenderscript
:library:generateDebugBuildConfig
:library:mergeDebugShaders
:library:compileDebugShaders
:library:generateDebugAssets
:library:mergeDebugAssets
:library:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateDebugResources
:library:mergeDebugResources
:library:processDebugManifest
:library:processDebugResources
:library:generateDebugSources
:library:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:library:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:library:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:library:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:library:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:library:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:library:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:library:extractDebugAnnotations
:library:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageDebugResources
:library:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:library:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:library:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug
:library:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:library:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:library:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug
:library:bundleDebug
:library:compileDebugSources
:library:assembleDebug
:library:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:library:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:library:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:library:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
:library:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
:library:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets
:library:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:library:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:library:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:library:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:library:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:library:incrementalDebugAndroidTestJavaCompilationSafeguard
:library:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac
:library:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileDebugAndroidTestSources

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.63 secs
```

gradle -stacktrace(not gradlew):

```
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:help

Welcome to Gradle 2.14.

To run a build, run gradle <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help

To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5.413 secs
```

Error in RelativeLayout.java:
[image]

[image]

Comment: That seems to be a linking problem. Android Studio is not fully compiling the project because of some issue with a library or dependency. Try to Clean and Rebuild Project and see if any strange message comes up on the Messages Log

Comment: Can you please share the error message

Comment: gradlew -stacktrace and share error

Comment: Edit @RicardoVieira

Comment: I use gradle instead of gradlew.It seems that every is good in log@ahmadaghazadeh

Comment: @wanglugao Cant figure out where the problem actually is. I experienced the same thing on my setup. As a workaround, you can define your own isLayoutRtl() method. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Can you try cleaning your project and rebuild

Comment: @Eenvincible not work(:

Answer (score 0):

From your information, there seems to be no error regarding your code. Usually, Android SDK classes have some red text/warnings associated to it since it can only link them while compiling.

Additionally, and even though there is not much documentation regarding `isLayoutRTL()` it seems that the method requires at least Android JellyBean for you to use it (which you seem to be targetting).

You could extend the RelativeLayout to your class and **Override** the method for your own advantag (if you need that, of course)

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private boolean isLayoutRtl() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            return View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL == getLayoutDirection();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own method using the following definition:

```
 static boolean isLayoutRtl(View v) {

     return ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(v) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL;
```

}

Comment: hi,Suhayl SH.thanks for your answer.But I want to know why this problem came out  and if there is some way to fix this.I used to set breakpoint in Android SDK source code in eclipse and the breakpoint works fine but it can't stop  in the right place in AS.It's very confusing..